# Copy css file from one subdirectory to another one in CONTAINER BLOB

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**Scenario:**

I copy .css file from one subdirectory to another in Azure Storage Container. It is done from C# code level in my application. This is css style file for my website. Unfortunately I received error in my browser console during loading page:

**Error**

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: 
"SOME_PATH/template/css/styles.css?d=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000".
```

**Knowledge:**

I know that it is why my file is sended as octet-stream instead of text/css. What can I do to say Azure to treat this file as text/css?
[image: AZURE BLOB]

**Edit: My code**

```
    string newFileName = fileToCopy.Name;
    StorageFile newFile = cmsDirectory.GetStorageFileReference(newFileName);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileToCopy.DownloadToStream(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        newFile.UploadFromStream(stream);
    }
```

where DownloadToStream and UploadToStream are methodes in my class:

```
CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(target);
```

and

```
CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(target);
```

CloudBlob is *CloudBlockBlob* type

Comment: Can you add your existing code? Knowing which functions you are using now will make it easier for people to recommend changes.

Comment: It is done, thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set content type of blob via property ContentType

look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contenttype

Answer (score 0):

Download AzCopy -  http://aka.ms/azcopy
If you specify /SetContentType without a value, AzCopy sets each blob or file's content type according to its file extension.
Run this command on Windows 
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder\ /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/ /DestKey:key /Pattern:ab /SetContentType

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

Use the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to modify the content-type string by hand for already existing file. Right click the blob file in explorer and the Left click on properties, scroll down to change the file format.

Comment: If you are a "programmer" then you should know how to run bash/powershell scripts in your code, lol.